# Question from Mathcounts competition

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The least positive integer that is divisible by $2, 3 ,4,$ and $5,$ and is also a perfect square, perfect cube, $4^{th}$ power, and $5^{th}$ power, can be written in the form $a^b$ for positive integers $a$ and $b$.  What is the least possible value of $a+b$?

The answer is $90$.

Even completely cheating with a computer I can't begin to figure out how to do this.  Could someone walk me through this like I haven't been in a math class for a long time?

Maybe I don't understand the problem or maybe floating point hell is blocking my attempts to cheat but even when I search all the possible $a+b=90$ for $a^b$ none of those are perfect powers of $5$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's call $a^b = x$. What are the prime factors of $x$? You know it must be divisible by $2$, $3$, $4$ and $5$, so it is of the form $x = 2^p 3^q 5^r$. All 3 of the exponents $p,q,r,$ must be divisible by $2, 3, 4$ and $5$, and the smallest integer that satisfies this is $60$. Thus:
$$x = 2^{60}3^{60}5^{60} = (2\cdot 3 \cdot 5)^{60} = 30^{60}.$$

This indeed satisfies that $a+b= 90$. Now, why can $30^{60}$ not be written as $c^d$ with $c+d < a+b$?

Comment: how do you know that p,q,r are also divisible by 2,3,4,5?  Something with logs I assume?

Comment: You need a perfect square, cube, 4th power and 5th power. So you must be able to rewrite $2^p$ as $(2^{p'})^2$, $(2^{p''})^3$, $(2^{p'''})^4$ and $(2^{p''''})^5$. The same holds for $q$ and $r$.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the source of your confusion, but a "5th power" is something of the form $n^5$, not $5^n$ (a "power of 5").

Comment: @deanmacgregor Even so, one of $5^{85}$ or $85^5$ is obviously such a "perfect power of $5$".

Comment: Nope that wasn't where the confusion came from.  I believe the problem with using the computer to cheat is that when the numbers get too big, if you don't use special packages the numbers get truncated because of memory space and things aren't, to the decimal, accurate anymore.